# Arduino digitalWrite affected by Serial.begin

Tags: serial-port, arduino, usb

I used following code to write to digital pin with Serial.begin.  Using Serial.begin affected my digital write.  The correct timing will not happen.

```
#define led 0

void setup() {

// put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin (115200);

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
delay(500);
digitalWrite(led,LOW);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(led,HIGH); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that I cannot using digital pin 0 and 1 as input or output when using serial.  Serial transmit(tx) and Receive (Rx) is on 1 and 0 respectively.  It is shown in the Arduino Uno board.  Solution was to use a different digital pin (2-13).

Comment: That is correct.  You should mark this answer as the accepted answer when you get a chance.